# Continuous map and reciprocal subset : sentence from my book

Tags: general-topology

In the book I read there is the following sentence :

"The map sending all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a single point of $\mathbb{R}^m$ is an example showing that a continuous map need not send open sets into open sets."

I don't understand this sentence. How does this example shows that a continuous map need to not send open sets into open sets ???

Comment: a single point in an Euclidean space is closed set assuming the $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ with Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open in the topological space $(\mathbb{R}^n,|\cdot|)$ and a singleton $\{x_0\}$, where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$, is closed in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (you can either see this directly or using that any finite subset of a Hausdorff space is closed). Furthermore, define a mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ by $f(x) := x_0$. Any constant mapping between topological spaces is continuous, but now we have that $f(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{x_0\}$ and thus this shows, that *not every continuous mapping is open*.

Comment: Oh ok. In fact I did'nt understand the english of the sentence. I thought they said that if a i have a continous map THEN open sets MUST to NOT map to open sets, that was my confusion. But with your answer I have a question : "any constant mapping is continuous". Is it just because $x_0$ is closed so any open from $\mathbb{R}^m$ will have the empty space as reciprocal. And empty space is an open, so any open will have an open preimage. So constant map is continuous. (I am a huge beginner in topology so I don't have big experience in thoose manipulations).

Comment: @StarBucK Your reasoning is quite right but you forgot cases where $x_0$ is contained in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$. If we do a topological proof of this fact, we simply take an open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ and observe that $$\begin{align*}f^{-1}(U) =\begin{cases}\mathbb{R}^n & x_0 \in U,\\\varnothing , & x_0 \notin U\end{cases}\end{align*}$$ which are both open.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, I didn't think about it so it was usefull, thanks !!

Comment: @StarBucK glad I could help. You're welcome!